# Ubuntu performance issues, long booting & lag when using multiple vscode

Tags: 20.04, performance

After installing ubuntu 20.04, I notice the boot took so much time, opening apps as well, but the worse is when I use vscode and run some watchers it's always lag and crash so I should to manually off the laptop,

some details about my lap (inspired by other questions)  
laptop specs: 
processor:  Intel® Core™ i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00GHz × 4 
Graphics Intel® HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2) 
8GB of ram 
OS TYPE: 64-bit 
Windowing System : X11

Free command (running just chrome):

```
free 
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        8040608     2685124     3795272      399536     1560212     4652248
Swap:        999420      931248       68172
```

Comment: "Installed over Windows" is irrelevant and this website is for Ubuntu and official derivatives only. I suggest [edit]ing the question to remove the last sentence and instead post a more comprehensive list of hardware specifications.

Comment: what kind of hardware info should I add, thank you

Comment: System drive, graphics, etc.

Comment: question edited

Comment: Surprisingly no mention of the system drive... It's this simple: If it's a HDD then everything will be slow.

Comment: Post the output of `free -h`

Comment: Your CPU speed doesn't seem too good and maybe you are on a hard disk   so consider upgrading to SSD..... With that much ram and CPU, I think so that this is a general speed you get, I think so that overclocking will also not work, consider upgrading the components of your PC

Comment: @ChanganAuto yes it's an HDD

Comment: so Getting an SDD will resolve this problem?

Comment: is the 19.0 version will work good this carstistic?